# if/ else statement not working?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i'm new to coding, and i cant figure out what i am doing wrong. every time i try to write an if/ else, it works up to the point that the statement is, and then it wont work.

this is what i wrote:

```
alert("welcome to chloe's quiz show!")
var name = prompt("contestant, what is your name?")
var help = prompt("is this your first time playing? type 'yes' or 'no'.")
if (help === yes){
alert("the game is easy! all you have to do is type the letter that corresponds with  the correct answer. then press 'ok'.")
confirm("lets get started!")
}
else{
confirm("lets get started then!")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Change this line:

```
if (help === yes)
```

to this:

```
if (help == "yes")
```

Since `yes` is not a variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (help === 'yes')
```

`yes` is an string, it has to be quoted